# Flutter - Controllable Sprite/Gif Animation on Overlay

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to show some animation when user tap on the screen. The animation need to be controllable too as it needs to be reset after each tap.

What I have tried:
 1. Show a Gif image in Overlay.

```
RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
var size = renderBox.size;
var offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

_myGif = Image.asset('images/mygif.gif', width: 100, height: 100,);

return OverlayEntry(
  builder: (context) => Positioned(
    left: offset.dx - 50.0 + size.width/2,
    top: offset.dy - 50.0 + size.height/2,
    child: Container(
      child: _myGif
    ),
  )
);
```

Problem: The Gif animation is not controllable. The animation also appears to be played from random frames and end at random frames each time.

2. Use third party widget (gif_ani)

   _animationCtrl = GifController(vsync: this, duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 1000), frameCount: 38);
   _mygifAnimation = GifAnimation(
     width: 100.0,
     height: 100.0,
     image: AssetImage('images/mygif.gif'),
     controller: _animationCtrl,
   );

Problem: It only works when it's not on an Overlay. When the GifAnimation is added as a child in Overlay it doesn't display at all.

3. Use Flame to run sprite sheet
   Problem: AnimationAsWidget doesn't fit my requirement as I need to control the animation. Other ways would make my code too complex as I'm not building a game.

Is there any solution on this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: see [getNextFrame](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Codec/getNextFrame.html) - `FrameInfo` has two properties: `image` and `duration` - that way you can select any frame you want from your gif file

Comment: @pskink Thanks for your reply. Can you explain more on this?

Comment: you have to iterate with `getNextFrame` until you get your start frame and then with any next frames you need to rebuild your `Image` widget until you get the last frame

Comment: @pskink Do you have an example which I can refers to? Image widget doesn't seems to allow me to call the getNextFrame method. Also how do I rebuild Image widget? I tried set it to null and re-initiate but the Gif wouldn't start animate from 1st frame.

Comment: OK then find MultiFrameImageStreamCompleter class and write similar custom ImageStreamCompleter - you can get it from image_stream.dart source file

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: basically you need to create a custom class that extends `ImageProvider` and custom class that extends `ImageStreamCompleter` - where custom `ImageProvider` will just forward the whole job to `ImageStreamCompleter`